# firefox web developer toolbar - can i see the posted data?

Tags: firefox, web-developer-toolbar

I am stuck using the Firefox web developer tool for testing out a web app.

I would like to see the contents of the "post" data that is sent - using the web developer tool, I can see a *log* of all the gets/posts and their responses, and I can see a little box called "Inspect Network Request".... but I cannot see the contents of the  POST data.

Is there some way to set the web developer to be slightly more useful?

Here is what I have to work with:

[image: Firefox's web developer]

Comment: get firebug! https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/ it has better network inspection. docs: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel

Comment: Also, the fidler debugging network proxy gives you a very detailed inspector and works with any browser. although the UI is a little clunky. http://www.telerik.com/fiddler